# Page not found handling without changing url Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have routes:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard, AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'signup', component: SignUpTenantComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
        { path: 'signin', component: SignInComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
        { path: ':url', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard, AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'page-not-found' }
    ];
```

And I have guard where I check url and if it's wrong then redirect on `PageNotfoundComponent`:

```
this.router.navigate(['page-not-found']);
```

And as a result I see in url `localhost:port/page-not-found`. But I want to do that without changing url.
If I add `{ skipLocationChange: true }` to `router.navigate` then I will see main url `localhost:port/`.
I want to see wrong url, for example `localhost:port/rgqadff` with `PageNotFoundComponent` content.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Not sure but try to change last object of Routes as: { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

Comment: Please replay if you got something.

Comment: It didn't help me

Comment: Please share you solution if you will find it.

Comment: Okay, no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the below way and it works fine, whatever you write it will show the NotFoundComponent without changing the url

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
   {path: '' , component: HomeComponent },
   {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
   {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to redirect on 404 page from service. How will you do that?

Comment: write anything after the backslash will redirect you to . and replace this { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent } in your routing array with { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

Comment: I think it would work if I don't have this route:
{ path: ':url', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard, AuthGuard] }

Comment: Angular redirects me constantly and doesn't load any component/page.

Comment: change it to { path: 'dashboard/:url', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard, AuthGuard] }

Comment: Yes, it works fine, but I need to do it for my route ":url"

Comment: Try to navigate in this way:
 this.router.navigate(['/404',"fsfsdfdf"])